# if i uncheck an element the check all in not getting unchecked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a page in which it shows all the week days and dates. i.e monday to sunday. When i click check all, all the week days are getting checked and when I click on that again they are getting unchecked. But when I uncheck a weekday i.e monday or tuesday the check all box is still checked.
here is my `html`

```
<div class=" row ">    
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 warning">
    <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input" [checked]="checkAll" (change)="onChangeCheckAll($event.target.checked)">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
    Select All
    </label>
</div>
<div class="row mgtop-5">
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input"  [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek(Monday, $event.target.checked)">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
        Monday
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4  ">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input" [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek(Tuesday, $event.target.checked)"  >
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
        Tuesday
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4  ">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input" [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek(Wednesday, $event.target.checked)"  >
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
        Wednesday
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mgtop-5">
    <div class="col-sm-4  ">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input" [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek(Thursday, $event.target.checked)"  >
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
        Thursday
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4  ">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input" [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek(Friday, $event.target.checked)"  >
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
        Friday
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input"  [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek(Saturday, $event.target.checked)" >
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
        Saturday
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mgtop-5">
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input"  [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek(Sunday , $event.target.checked)" >
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
        Sunday
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 mgtop-5"></div>
</div>
```

here is the JavaSCript

```
// check for particular weekday
onChangeCheckWeek(week: any, isChecked: boolean) {
    if (isChecked) {
      this.checkAll = false;
    } else {
      this.checkAll = false;
    }
  }



// check all weekdays
onChangeCheckAll(isChecked: boolean) {
    if (isChecked) {
      this.checkAllWeek = true;

    } else {
      this.checkAll = false;
      this.checkAllWeek = false;

    }
  }
```

Comment: This is normal that the method onChangeCheckWeek has if(isChecked) condition 2 times ?

Comment: What abut again you check the weak days?

Comment: it is not coming even if i keep it one time.

Comment: Your onChangeCheckWeek code looks strange. you are checking two times for isChecked and you never update `checkAllWeek`

Answer (score 0):

let me ease your life

```
<input #checkAll type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" (change)="getStatus()" (click)="handleCheckAll()">
```

In your TS

```
@ViewChild('checkAll') checkAll: ElementRef;
checkedDays: string[] = [];
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'You get the idea'];

getStatus() {
  let el = this.checkAll.nativeElement;
  if (this.checkedDays.length === this.days.length) { el.checked = true; }
  else if (!this.checkedDays.length) { el.checked = false; }
  else { el.indeterminate = true; }
}

handleCheckAll() {
  if (this.checkedDays.length === this.days.length) { this.checkedDays = []; }
  else if (!this.checkedDays.length) { this.checkedDays = this.days; }
  else { /* Chose what to do when 1 to 6 days are checked */}
}
```

All you need to to now, is push the day you clicked into checkedDays array, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

as per your logic you don't need to check any condition in `onChangeCheckWeek` function.

```
onChangeCheckWeek(week: any, isChecked: boolean) {
         this.checkAll = false; //           }
```

### Your problem

you are **missing the single quote** in parameter value in your **all** `onChangeCheckWeek` event. So the event doesn't triggers.

### Solution:

The `onChangeCheckWeek` event should be like `(change)="onChangeCheckWeek('Wednesday', $event.target.checked)"`  instead of  `(change)="onChangeCheckWeek(Wednesday, $event.target.checked)"` . see you are missed the single quote in `'Wednesday'`.

Answer (score 0):

**hey! thank you for the help guys but I got it this way**
I added an [(ngModel)]=selectAllWeekDays to select all and in the ts file I added this.selectAllWeekDays=false in else statement. Have a look at the HTML here

```
 <div class=" row ">    
 <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 warning">
 <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input" 
 [checked]="checkAll" (change)="onChangeCheckAll($event.target.checked)" 
 [(ngModel)]="selectAllWeekDays">
 <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
 <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
 Select All 
 </label>
 </div>
```

And this is the TS file:

```
onChangeCheckWeek(week:any ,  isChecked: boolean) {

if (isChecked) {
  this.checkAll = false;
} else {
  this.checkAll = false;
  this.selectAllWeekDays= false;
}
```

}